# How to delete all recordings in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crud

I need to make endpoint /products
that will be deletes all products from the storage. But I dont understand how to make this,
now i have delete method thats delete only one product by id
this is my controller

```
  # DELETE /products/1 or /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: "Product was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

My index.html

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Products</h1>

<table class="table table-striped ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>

      <tr>
        <td><%= product.name %></td>
        <td><%= product.price %></td>
        <td><button type = 'button' class="btn btn-outline-info"><%= link_to 'Show', product %></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger"><%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<%= link_to 'New Product', new_product_path %>
```

and routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :products
  root 'products#index'
end
```

I need to create a button that will delete all products from the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not one of the seven standard REST actions, so you don't get extra help from rails here. One of the ways you could go about this is to define a custom action.

```rb
# routes.rb
resources :products do
  post :delete_all, on: :collection
end

# products_controller.rb
def delete_all
  Product.delete_all
  redirect_to :products_path
end
```

And insert a link/button that does a POST to `/products/delete_all`. Should look more or less like this:

```
link_to 'Destroy All', delete_all_products_path, method: :post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```